# Is $V_\alpha \cap H_{\omega_1}$, for $\omega < \alpha < \omega_1$, absolute for models of ZF?

Tags: set-theory

Let $\alpha$ be an ordinal such that $\omega < \alpha < \omega_1$. Is $V_\alpha \cap H_{\omega_1}$ absolute for models of ZF?

Note: $H_{\omega_1}$ denotes the set of hereditarily countable sets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, of course not. Just adding reals will increase $V_{\omega+1}\cap H_{\omega_1}$. And therefore any other $V_\alpha\cap H_{\omega_1}$.

Also, note that if $V=L$, then $V_\alpha\cap H_{\omega_1}=L_\alpha$, and if $H_{\omega_1}\neq L_{\omega_1}$, then at some $\alpha$ the intersection is no longer $L_\alpha$. (Recall that $(H_{\omega_1})^L=L_{\omega_1}$.)